# Notifications in app only, not in notification center

Tags: android, notifications

is it possible to have notifications pop up, make a sound and be shortly visible at the top of the screen but not be logged via the notification center?

My idea is to have the user be notified of any important actions. But while the user is inside the app the notifications should not pool up inside the notification center. When the user is not actively using the app I will start a background service with a websocket and get further notifications for the user to be shown via the notification center.

So it it possible to differentiate between the two types. Similar to what whatsapp is doing?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the desired effect seems to be to just cancel the notification by ID once it has been passed to the notification manager:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#cancel(int)

Comment: It seems that on Android 12 devices this leads to the popup not being displayed at all. Maybe a delay between sending and canceling will help but this feels really dirty.